# How to configure Xcode to not go to Debug Navigator upon run?

Tags: xcode4

How to configure Xcode to not go to `Debug Navigator` by default, upon run? Upon `<command-R>`, i'd like to stay on `Project Navigator`, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is under Behaviors in the Preferences pane.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Monolos answer:

Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Behaviours -> OpenGL ES capture starts

then untick the box next to "Show navigator 'Debug Navigator'"